# How to run a script each time I login AND unlock session

Tags: login, lock-screen

In Saucy salamander I need to run a script each time I login then each time I unlock the session after manual lock or auto sleep.
I can't use "Startup Application" for that because it wouldn't trigger on unlock.

Comment: Related question on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28181/4292

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1818895&s=daf22a3ee24bfe637d400f4aaeb8c414&p=11136279#post11136279), which was made by [Ubuntu Forums user opus1](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=264927).  Maybe it can help.

---

This is what the post gives as a solution:

> For anyone interested, here's what I did: I looked at the logs
>   (specifically /var/logs/auth.log) and saw that an entry is made when
>   ever the password is checked and accepted. My log said:
>
> ```
> Aug  7 14:10:57 mumble gnome-screensaver-dialog: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
> ```
>
> Ultimately I found an application called "Swatch" which monitors a log
>   for you and will run a script when a string that you specify appears
>   in that log. Swatch requires a config file (.swatchrc), and mine looks
>   like this:
>
> ```
> watchfor /unlocked login keyring/
>   exec /root/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/wakeServer
> ```
>
> where "/unlocked login keyring/" is the string to look for and "exec"
>   defines the script to run when it is found. My wakeServer script looks
>   like this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> #wake the server
> wakeonlan AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
>
> #record info in the log file
> myVar="woke server at login:"
> echo "$myVar">>/home/me/.serverWake.log
> date>>/home/me/.serverWake.log
> ```
>
> where "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF" is the MAC address of my server.
>
> Swatch will need to be entered as a start-up application (create an
>   entry in System | Preferences | Startup applications called
>   "runSwatch" and make the command "swatch --tail-file /var/log/auth.log
>   --daemon". (In Debian, only root can read logs So the start up command needs to be prefaced with "sudo" and swatch will need to be added to
>   the sudoers file without a password. In Ubuntu it appears non-root
>   users can read logs. There could be a security issue with granting
>   password-less access to swatch, but in my case it seems acceptable).
>
> So far it has worked perfectly!

Comment: Thank you GabrielF. I now have to understand the commands after dbus-monitor...

Comment: The link doesn't use `dbus-monitor`. You found a different solution?

Comment: @GabrielF HAAAA thanks mate works like magic, this is exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: /var/logs/auth.log does not exist on my Ubuntu 17.10 for some reason.  I dislike this answer because it requires installing a special package, Swatch, and understanding low-level things when Gnome should provide a way to run a user-supplied command upon unlock, separate from the startup scripts. At least https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/21372 uses dbus-monitor which seems to be installed already, but still requires some low level knowledge to run that in the background from a startup script.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 the file `auth.log` does not exists at `/var/logs/auth.log` but at `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` will be the place you want to use for that process.  `.bashrc` holds users' profile and all of configurations, and that's what system will read first thing when you log in, therefore that's where you want to put your codes for your customized scripts to run upon logging in.

Here's an example from my codes that I use.  This is code I added to the bottom line of .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.myscripts ]; then
. ~/.myscripts
fi
```

And `.myscripts` holds my scripts in bash shell that I want to be fired off when I log in.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work although


~$ ls -aF .my*
.myscripts*


and I added the reference to .bashrc. I tried tweaking .bashrc with force prompt color just to see how this work and I don't even need to unlog to see the change, just close re-open the terminal.


when i run . /.myscripts from terminal the script works ok but is not triggered when I log in a locked tty7.

Comment: I believe I begin to understand. This will maybe work in addition with the link below given by GabrielF. Thank you Faron.

Comment: .bashrc isn't sourced when you lockout or login a graphical session.

Comment: Yes, but I ended in understanding it is a place from which one can launch a resident script (the one that will monitor logon). An other guy proposed a different solution: /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_kill-notify-osd https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454

Comment: upvote for @Braiam in pointing out when it's not sourced upon lock out or logging via graphical.  No wonder why few of my scripts didn't function properly.